# When lazy injecting IEnumerable getting double entries

Tags: c#, autofac, code-injection, lazy-evaluation

I'm using Autofac and inject all regtries of an interface for some reason this must be lazy. But I got double entries in this list. There are 3 plugins but my ienum contains 6. Every plugin is injected twice. I could use Distinct, but this seems to be a hack.

```
public WorkInProgressService(IEnumerable<Lazy<IWorkInProgressPlugin>> plugins)
{
  this.plugins = plugins;
}
```

I checked and it is definetly not registered twice.

Comment: Where are you registering `IEnumerable<Lazy<IWorkInProgressPlugin>>`?

Comment: I don't want to get plugins until they are needed because they can change until that point.

Comment: why don't you make it Lazy<IEnumerable<IWorkInProgressPlugin>>

Comment: Good Question, i thought this is what i supposed i needed. I tried  Lazy<IEnumerable<IWorkInProgressPlugin>> and it changed nothing

Comment: Transposition of Lazy<> and IEnumerable<> will never make a difference in how many elements you get back. The only difference would be whether all the services are resolved at once or one-by-one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I'm guessing that you registered each one twice.

You can get a little more info about the registrations if you put run this code somewhere that you have access to your container and examine the objects in the array:

```cs
var reg = container.ComponentRegistry
            .RegistrationsFor(new TypedService(typeof (IWorkInProgressPlugin)))
            .ToArray();
```

If you're getting 6 plugins in your parameter, you'll get 6 registration entries.

Autofac's collection support is provided by [this class](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs). It gets every registration matching the service element, resolves each one, and puts them into an array.

Autofac's `Lazy<>` support [is provided by this class](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/LazyDependencies/LazyRegistrationSource.cs). It takes all registrations of the inner service and for each one, creates a new registration that wraps it in a `Lazy`.

Comment: I double checked and it is definetly not registered twice.

Comment: Without seeing the code for your registrations, there's not much more anyone can do for you. I'm still willing to bet that you're unwittingly registering your plugins twice.

Comment: You were correct it was registered twice. But it were not the classes but the hole module was registered twice.